# First time using mysql...ImportError:

Tags: mysql, macos, flask

I have looked all over and tried everything to resolve this issue for a day or two, but haven't had any luck.

I am using flask and sql for the first time(macOS), I have everything installed. But I am guessing that it is either installed incorrectly, or in the wrong folder.

I installed sql directly from their website, I then followed this advice here...

```
$ open -t .bash_profile

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

I know that it does work because I am able to go into the database in my terminal. my Flask app does work (it runs before adding all of the sql code), but the only thing I am having trouble with is running my program after importing(from flask_mysqldb import MySQL).

This is the tutorial I am following as well, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6L3HNyXEais

my error is here...

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/Users/jonathanmast/flask_prac/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Please add an OS tag (Mac?). Also please edit your question and indicate how you installed flask and sql, and what command are you executing that leads to this error. The error itself just says that your are missing a library, so yes, something has gone wrong during installation.

Comment: Thanks, I updated original post.